# How to to enable folder sharing for any folder between two windows system who share same Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

How to to enable folder sharing between two windows system who share same Wi-Fi connection?

I have 2 PC both has USB Wi-Fi device and internet is running both using Wi-Fi.

But How to share a folder on one PC and access that folder from another one.

1 PC has Windows 7 (64 bit) Home Premium and another has 32 bit Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Since both machines have Windows 7, you can use [Homegroups](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/homegroup-from-start-to-finish).

Comment: it only allows to share libraries

Comment: Not true. You can navigate to the folder, pull down the 'Share with' tab on the organizer bar, and select 'Homegroup'.